# MS Access Indexed View

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Is it possible to add a index on a Ms Access View ?

I am trying to run this query:

```
CREATE INDEX MyCustomViewIndex ON [MyView] (MyColumn) WITH DISALLOW NULL
```

and I am getting this error message.

> Cannot execute data definition
>   statements on linked data sources.

Any suggestions?

Regards,
Alex

EDIT:

My View definition:

```
create view MyView as SELECT TableA.Field1, MyUnionQuery.Field2
FROM TableA, MyUnionQuery
```

MyUnionQuery definition:

```
Select * from ViewX
UNION select * from ViewY
```

All the tables are in the same MDB file

Comment: Where is your linked table stored?  Another mdb, SQL Server, some other backend?

Comment: all the tables and views involved are in the same mdb file

Comment: Why do you think the solution is to index the view rather than the underlying table the view is drawing its data from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual for Access (ACE, Jet, whatever) the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243831%28v=office.12%29.aspx) is vague: it talks about 'tables' and of course a `VIEW` is a 'viewed table' but I think in this case it specifically refers to 'base tables'. I strongly suspect indexes are not supported for Access `VIEW`s.

When I try to create one using SQL DDL I too get the error, "Cannot execute data definition statements on linked data sources." Here's some VBA code to reproduce the error (creates a new .mdb in temp folder, no references required just paste into a VBA code module e.g. in Excel):

```
Sub NoIndexedViews()

  On Error Resume Next
  Kill Environ$("temp") & "\DropMe.mdb"
  On Error GoTo 0

  Dim cat
  Set cat = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")
  With cat
    .Create _
        "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & _
        Environ$("temp") & "\DropMe.mdb"
    With .ActiveConnection

      Dim Sql As String
      Sql = _
      "CREATE TABLE T (col1 INTEGER);"
      .Execute Sql

      Sql = _
      "CREATE VIEW V (col1) AS SELECT col1 FROM T;"
      .Execute Sql

      On Error Resume Next

      Sql = _
      "CREATE INDEX idx ON V (col1) WITH DISALLOW NULL"
      .Execute Sql

      MsgBox Err.Description

    End With
    Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing
  End With
End Sub
```

I don't have *any* linked data sources in my .mdb so I conclude the error being shown is spurious and misleading. But the fact remains, an index cannot be created on an Access `VIEW`.

Comment: I think it's possible to create temporary indexes on ADO recordsets, but I could be wrong about that. I recall a long discussion in one of the Access newsgroups about this where somebody coded up the same thing in DAO using transactions.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: Yes, you are referring to the [Optimize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property of a recordset Field. This is used to speed up calls to the recorset Find and Filter methods. However, note the OP is trying to create a `NOT NULL` constraint on a `VIEW` (a.k.a. query object).

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't want that index that disallows Nulls to be on the underlying field, rather than in the VIEW. If it's necessary for the VIEW, why would it not also be necessary in the underlying table?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message it is a linked data source. That means that the table is not inside access but linked in.

Since Access does not control the table it cannot do the requested operataion.

Where is the table that the data comes from?

Comment: all entities are in the same MDB file